# I want to create a simple input box that then calculates 80% as you type but without using a form

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I don't know how to pickup the value from the input box if I don't use a form...
So I want to replicate the following but without using form tags...

```
<form action="#" name="myconvert">
100% of value = 
<input type="text" name="percent100" 
onkeyup=" document.myconvert.percent80.value = Math.round((0.8 * document.myconvert.percent100.value)*100)/100" />
so 80% = <input type="text" name="percent80" disabled />
```

Please help

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" name="percent100"  
onkeyup=" document.getElementById('percent80').value = Math.round((0.8 * document.getElementById('percent100').value)*100)/100" /> 
so 80% = <input type="text" name="percent80" disabled />
```

Comment: Just for the record and for people new to JS:using inline Javascript is a *bad* thing. In examples it's okay but it's almost never a good idea to mix Javascript and HTML in the same file. That gets messy real fast.

Comment: I agree you but... you should consider that in this forum there are people with different level of knowledge that is why sometime we just answer the question as they are asked: we can’t always “refactor” the code to stick to the best practice even because it could make the answer more difficult to understand especially for a beginner/junior developer. I hope it makes sense

Comment: For oezi:the best way would be using Jquery insted even because it is cross-browsing.Anyway you can even use getElementById with the name of the tag instead of the Id but of course you have to bear in mind few things :-) have a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536437(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Give the input an id, for example `<input type="text" id="percent80" />`, then use `document.getElementById('percent80').value = ...`

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
<input type="text" id="txt" onKeyUp="show80()" />
<div id="show"></div>
<script type="text/javaScript">
function show80(){
        $('#show').html($('#txt').val()*0.8);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the form tags, just let Javascript target an input tag with a certain id.

```
Type your value here <input id="source" type="text"><br/>
<br/>
<span id="result"></span>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#source').keyup(function(){
        $('#result').html( parseFloat($(this).val()) * 0.8 );
    });
</script>
```